# How to delete files that does not exist in local position but still exist in origin?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

When using git, after I delete some files on my local computer and push the repo to origin, the origin only shows change of editing file, but the deleted files still exist on origin. How to delete files in origin that do not exist locally? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the deletion and commit it before pushing to the remote?

Comment: How did you delete your file locally ? You have to tell git that you deleted them with `git rm`.

Comment: Did you do `git add` on the deleted file or `git rm` to delete the file? It's possible you only committed the edits and the deletes are still sitting there waiting. Running `git status` will show what state they're in.

Comment: @RomainValeri  Thanks! Do I need to do `git rm` after I delete the file by `rm` or `git rm` will help me delete the file locally? Besides, If I forget to use `git rm` and only use `rm`, is there anyway to automatically delete file on origin that does not exist on local computer?

Answer (score 2):

I think the file which you deleted is unstage/untracked by git thats why it didn't push that .

**Try these things :**

1) If you are using vscode install github extension and check that where are those deleted file .

2) If you don't have vscode and don't want to use extension then try [git-show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) this will show all everything in a commit .

3) Try to --force push (not good practice) .